# Return List of flagged errors in data based on SQL queries in spring java

Tags: java, sql, spring, jspx

How do I generate a list of errors in data in spring java? I have an entity with 4 fields.

Entity-apartment

**fields:**

- 1.name
- 2.tenants
- 3.female_tenants
- 4.male_tenants

tenants = female_tenants + male_tenants

How do I list the apartments where number of the tenants is equal to female_tenants + male_tenants?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Please state your question clearly and ask only one question at a time.

Comment: assuming i have fields as stated which don't add up, how do i output a list with all rows with errors

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in SQL ... something like this should work.  the "coalesce" function is just to avoid the pesky NULL comparisons/additions.

```
select
name
from
apartment
where
coalesce(tenants,0) <> (coalesce(female_tenants,0) + coalesce(male_tenants,0))
```